# How to do letter-spacing for a single word?

Tags: letterspacing

How can I reduce space between letters for a specific word in my LaTeX document? I prefer not to use any additional package.

Comment: could you please be more specific about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: For one off "emergency" spacing you can insert negative space with `\!`

Comment: Maybe: `\newcommand*{\NS}{\hspace*{-1pt}}` and then  `s\NS i\NS n\NS g\NS l\NS e`?  But are you really loading no packages? Some of the ones you do load may provide other or better possibilities.

Comment: Can you give a hint as to what this word might be? Is every instance of this word in the document supposed to be (negatively) letter-spaced automatically, or should only one instance be (negatively) letter-spaced? Do you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! If you will provide a small, complete document with `\documentclass{...}` on beginning and used packages for fonts and ending with `\end{document}` you will give us more insight of your problem. Now you left us guessing ...

Comment: Some good reason for avoid `microtype` use? Almost any document just look nicer with that package,  and moreover, for your purpose is enough with some like :  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
TEST\SetTracking{ encoding = *}{-150}
\textls{TEST}
\end{document}`

Comment: Maybe `\kern` with negative space, if it is something like a logo?

Comment: you can use \scalebox (graphicx package) to literally shrink the width.